# How to list all rows from table and display specific column data from wordpress database

Tags: database, plugins, wordpress

I have table called wp_email_subscription and inside table I have rows of emails from subscribed users. Each row contains id, email, and name column.

I have also created admin page for plugin where I would like to list all emails from subscribed table.

Basically I don't know how to use wpdb functions, I have read wpdb instructions from wp website but I don't understand.

what I need is to select all from wp_email_subscription and foreach row to display email and name column in list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you have to use `global wpdp` variable and `get_result` function in your code page like this...

```
global $wpdb;

$row = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_email_subscription");

foreach ( $row as $row ) 
{ echo "email:".$row->email.";} //$row->your_column_name in table
```

like this, you can access all columns by `$variable->col_name`